# Can't replace a string containing an operator

Tags: batch-file, replace, operators

I use a batch to find and replace an expression into a file (adapted from @MC ND).

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "Var1=blabla=toto"
set "Var2=replace"
set "Var3=test.bat"

   for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%Var3%" ^& break ^> "%Var3%" ') do (
       set "line=%%i"

       setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
       >>"%Var3%" echo(!line:%Var1%=%Var2%!
       endlocal
   )
```

But it doesn't work when I try an expression that contains an operator like "blabla=toto"

input file:

```
 blabla=toto
```

The result that I got:

```
 toto=replace=toto
```

The result that I want:

```
 replace
```

Does anyone have any idea about that ?

Comment: The `cmd` code that handles substring replacement searchs the first `=` to separate search and replacement parts. So you can not include any `=` in the search part as it will be seen as the search end / replace start. [JRepl](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) can be an alternative

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you protect your own sanity and leverage `powershell.exe` instead:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Var1=blabla=toto"
Set "Var2=replace"
Set "Var3=test.bat"
PowerShell -NoP "(GC '%Var3%') -Replace '%Var1%','%Var2%'|SC '%Var3%'" 2>Nul
```

Or considering your previous question was receiving the three variables as arguments:

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "(GC '%~3') -Replace '%~1','%~2'|SC '%~3'" 2>Nul
```

Comment: As the `-replace` operator is RegEx based, it may be advised to escape chars in var1 otherwise interpreted as [RegEx chars](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html) `\|[](){}+.*?` => `PowerShell -NoP "(GC '%Var3%') -Replace [RegEx]::Escape('%Var1%'),'%Var2%'|SC '%Var3%'" 2>Nul`

Comment: Relative to the question posed, there are no RegEx special characters in their vars. If the questioner wishes to do that, it is outside of the scope of the question and therfore this answer, but they're free to implement that useful modification should they wish to do so..